# Wrap NoUiSlider in angular2 component - how to manage events

Tags: typescript, angular, nouislider

I am trying to wrap NoUiSlider (from Refreshless.com) in an Angular2 component (which I am not sure is a good idea in itself; open to get advice on this as well).
So far I have been able to create a slider instance and manage its events via a function. The function though is external to my component which makes it impossible to export such event as an Output property of the component I am trying to create.
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance. Here is the code

```
///<reference path="../typings/nouislider/nouislider.d.ts" />

import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-slider',
  template: `
    <div #sliderDomElement id="slider"></div>
  `,
})

export class Slider implements AfterViewInit { 
    @ViewChild('sliderDomElement') sliderDomElement;
    noUiSlider: any;
    @Input() start: number[];
    @Input() range: any;  
    @Input() pips: any; 
    @Output() end: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        noUiSlider.create(this.sliderDomElement.nativeElement, 
          {start: this.start,
           range: this.range,
           pips: this.pips
        });
        this.noUiSlider = this.sliderDomElement.nativeElement.noUiSlider;
        this.noUiSlider.on('end', logSlider);
    }

}


function logSlider(inNoUiSlider: any) {
    // the event is managed by this fuction, but I can not raise the event defined as Output by the component
    console.log(inNoUiSlider);
}
```

After some more digging (in Typescript) I seem to have found a solution, i.e. the use of arrow function expressions. Here the new code

```
///<reference path="../typings/nouislider/nouislider.d.ts" />

import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-slider',
  template: `
    <div #sliderDomElement id="slider"></div>
  `,
})

export class Slider implements AfterViewInit { 
    @ViewChild('sliderDomElement') sliderDomElement;
    noUiSlider: any;
    @Input() start: number[];
    @Input() range: any;  
    @Input() pips: any; 
    @Output() end: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

public myLogSlider = (inValues: any[]) => {
    console.log(inValues);
    this.end.next(inValues);
}
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        noUiSlider.create(this.sliderDomElement.nativeElement, 
          {start: this.start,
           range: this.range,
           pips: this.pips
        });
        this.noUiSlider = this.sliderDomElement.nativeElement.noUiSlider;
        this.noUiSlider.on('end', logSlider);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Duo to the fact that still somebody might stumble over this question:

There is a library that provides such on GitHub
https://github.com/tb/ng2-nouislider
You can use it in reactive forms or template forms.

To the question if that is a reasonable idea:

- (pro) It gives you and others easier and cleaner way to use the NoUiSlider in Angular2
- (pro) You are independent from the underlaying library
- (contra) As it is a wrapper (and wrappers usually do that) it takes slightly more Cpu power to calculate since you will e.g. wrap an extra function around an already existing one or use an extra variable to write cleaner code. But the performance difference will be so small, I'd say that in most context's it won't matter.

So in conclusion I would say, it's a good thing to do so duo to a better code maintainability.